# How to use systemd kernel argument systemd.journald.forward_to_syslog

Tags: systemd, systemd-journald

I like to provision several machines via PXE, and pass the kernel argument `systemd.journald.forward_to_syslog` to all machine, so I can monitor all the logs from a central place. (I can't change the machine config, this is the first boot, and only boot)

From the [docs](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/journald.conf.html#ForwardToSyslog=) it seems like this option is a boolean true/false option, but I was not able to find how to set the detestation for the syslog server. I also tried to use it like this `systemd.journald.forward_to_syslog=1.2.3.4` , but I don't see and traffic generated to my syslog server.

Have any one tried it before ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Systemd-journald does not support sending messages over the network. This option controls forwarding to a *local* syslog daemon, which is expected to listen at /run/systemd/journal/syslog.

(However, this is not the recommended method anyway. When using either syslog-ng or rsyslogd, it is more reliable to let the syslog daemon pull the journal messages by directly reading the `.journal` files, while keeping the "forward" option disabled. This allows syslogd to accurately preserve all metadata fields that go beyond the standard BSD Syslog format.)

In short: you will need to install an actual syslog daemon, configure it to read .journal files (using the `system()` source in syslog-ng or the `imjournal` module in rsyslogd), and tell it to forward the imported messages over the network.

Answer (score 0):

After searching about this matter more, seem like `systemd.journald.forward_to_syslog` is not the right way to tackle this.

Also found this [answer](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/7170) by systemd creator Lennart Poettering

> Doing this inside of journald is not pretty as journald is started long before the network is up, and would mean we'd have to turn off the sandbox it is living in. By doing this in a separate mini daemon instead, we gain asynchronous behavior (i.e. as soon as netlogd starts it can "catch up" with what happened in the meantime), and journald doesn't need to be network facing.

and the recommended way is to use [netlogd](https://github.com/systemd/systemd-netlogd)
(which not seems to be per-compiled with CentOS/Fedora machines )